# Logging DJI error codes to ofstream

Tags: c++, dji-sdk

This may be a simple C++ question, but I'm having difficulty logging error code messages to an ofstream (logging to a file during flight to diagnose issues).

This is a code block of what I'd like to log

```
if (ACK::getError(startAck))
{
   ACK::getErrorCodeMessage(startAck, __func__);
}
```

The line in the conditional returns null, and from what I am seeing, **func** is what logs the error to the standard output.

Anyone have any insight on how I could bring that message into an ofstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 2018, the only way to log error messages to a file is to redirect your `stdout` stream to a file when running the program at a terminal.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. That's actually the solution I ended up going with. Works fine